# DiscriminatorColumn not applied in JPA

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I have a base class called `User` and I am using Single Table inheritance strategy.

```java
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "User_Type")
public class User {
```

And I have one more class called `Artist` which extends `User` class.

```java
@Entity(name = "Artist")
@DiscriminatorValue("Artist")
public class Artist extends User {
```

The tables in the database are created and I have 2 rows with 2 artist types.

[image: the "User_type" column is created in the database]

This is how I am trying to get the Artists from the database. **instanceof Artist** seems to not work properly, "artists" list remains null.

```java
EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
em.getTransaction().begin();
List <User> result = em.createQuery("from User", User.class).getResultList();
em.getTransaction().commit();
em.close();
//get only the artists from the result list
//error here
for (User u: result) {
   if (u instanceof Artist) {
      artists.add((Artist) u);
   }
}
```

When I am debugging it all columns are listed except the `User_Type` column and I think this is the problem. How can I solve this?

[image: debugging mode database rows]

**UPDATE**
The problem was that the entity classes were not specified in the "persistence.xml" .

Comment: Huh, that's weird. Was the schema created using Hibernate? What happens when you use `"FROM Artist"` instead? Are you sure `Artist` is getting picked up during entity scan?

Comment: @crizzis I fixed the problem... I had to specify all entity classes in the persistence.xml.. Now it s working.